# Escape Space in PHP LDAP DN

Tags: php, ldap

I struggling to search LDAP with the BaseDN. Im fairly certain its because of the SPACE in the OU. It does work with a simple DN (No spaces)

This is my DN:

```
$ldap_dn = "OU=Distribution Groups,OU=MyCompany,DC= mycompany,DC=localnet";
```

I have tried "\ ", &20, \20 Nothing works.

I have also tried:

```
$ldap_dn_bad = "OU=Distribution Groups,OU= MyCompany,DC= mycompany,DC=localnet";
$ldap_dn  = ldap_escape($ldap_dn_bad, null, LDAP_ESCAPE_FILTER);
```

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of the LDAP String Representation of Distinguished Names RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4514)

Spaces are allowed without need to be escaped inside the value of an AttributeValue, but not leading/traling spaces in the value :

- `OU=Distribution Groups` : OK -> value is `Distribution Groups`
- `DC= mycompany` : NOT OK -> value is `[ ]mycompany`. (without brackets)

I would try either :

- to replace them with `\x20`
- to simply remove the trailing/leading space on all AttributeValue (with http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ldap-explode-dn.php to iterate on each value)